# SIGABRT. How get line from code, which issues error?

Tags: xcode, llvm, sigabrt, dylib

Use xCode 4.5 SDK 6.0 + cocos2d 2.1

Then xCode issues SIGABRT, we see this:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuZm2.png)

In log we read method, which issues error. For example: [IntroLayer zeroMethods]; **It's ok.**
And we need find this method in project by hands.
But, in previuos version (~4.0), xCode shows the line that caused the error.

So, how get line from code, which issues error? ([IntroLayer zeroMethods]; - line 24, IntroLayer.m)

I want it to be so:
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5011K.png)

Comment: Well, go to IntroLayer.m, scroll to line 24, voila...

Comment: You might want to consider setting Xcode to break on exceptions : http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: Alladinian, this is what need. Thank you!